# Overlap in the data - Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

[image: I have a dataframe like this below]

I want to find the overlap between each brand like when I compare HORLICKS VS BOOST, I will have to find whats HORLICKS only percentage , BOOST ONLY and their intersection.Its basically a venn diagram problem.I have computed for one combination. But I want to compute for all combination , like HORLICKS vs BOOST,HORLICKS VS nESTLE , HORLICKS vs BOURNVITA etc.

Can somebody help me ? I am new to spark

Below is my code:

```
  val A_storeList = sourceDf.where(col("CATEGORY").equalTo(item1(0)) and col("SUBCATEGORY").equalTo(item1(1)) and col("product_char_name").equalTo(item1(2)) and col("product_charval_dsc").equalTo(item1(3))).select("store_id").collect().map(_(0)).distinct
  val B_storeList = sourceDf.where(col("CATEGORY").equalTo(item2(0)) and col("SUBCATEGORY").equalTo(item2(1)) and col("product_char_name").equalTo(item2(2)) and col("product_charval_dsc").equalTo(item2(3))).select("store_id").collect().map(_(0)).distinct
  val aAndBstoreList = A_storeList.intersect(B_storeList)
  val AunionB_storeList = A_storeList.union(B_storeList).distinct
  val AOnly_storeList = A_storeList.diff(B_storeList)
  val Bonly_storeList = B_storeList.diff(A_storeList)
  val subSetOfSourceDf = sourceDf.withColumn("Versus",lit(item1(3)+"Vs"+item2(3)))
  val A = subSetOfSourceDf.where(col("store_id").isin(A_storeList:_*)).withColumn("Venn",lit("A"))
  val B = subSetOfSourceDf.where(col("store_id").isin(B_storeList:_*)).withColumn("Venn",lit("B"))
  val AandB = subSetOfSourceDf.where(col("store_id").isin(aAndBstoreList:_*)).withColumn("product_charval_dsc",when(col("product_charval_dsc").equalTo(item1(3)),item1(3)+" and "+item2(3)).when(col("product_charval_dsc").equalTo(item2(3)),item1(3)+" and "+item2(3)).otherwise(col("product_charval_dsc"))).withColumn("Venn",lit("AintersectB"))
  val AunionB = subSetOfSourceDf.where(col("store_id").isin(AunionB_storeList:_*)).withColumn("product_charval_dsc",when(col("product_charval_dsc").equalTo(item2(3)),item1(3)+" and "+item2(3)).when(col("product_charval_dsc").equalTo(item1(3)),item1(3)+" and "+item2(3)).otherwise(col("product_charval_dsc"))).withColumn("Venn",lit("AunionB"))
  val AOnly = subSetOfSourceDf.where(col("store_id").isin(AOnly_storeList:_*)).withColumn("Venn",lit("AOnly"))
  val BOnly = subSetOfSourceDf.where(col("store_id").isin(Bonly_storeList:_*)).withColumn("Venn",lit("BOnly"))
  val allInOne = A.union(B.union(AandB.union(AunionB).union(AOnly.union(BOnly))))

  val divisor = allInOne.where((col("Venn").equalTo("A").and(col("product_charval_dsc").equalTo(item1(3)))) or (col("Venn").equalTo("B").and(col("product_charval_dsc").equalTo(item2(3)))) )
    .groupBy("CATEGORY","SUBCATEGORY","product_char_name").agg(sum("SALVAL") as "TOTAL")

  val finalDf1 = allInOne.groupBy("CATEGORY","SUBCATEGORY","product_char_name","product_charval_dsc","Venn")
    .agg(sum("SALVAL") as "SALVAL")
    .where(col("product_charval_dsc").equalTo(item1(3)) or col("product_charval_dsc").equalTo(item2(3)) or col("product_charval_dsc").equalTo(item1(3)+" and "+item2(3)))

  val outputDf =finalDf1.join(divisor,Seq("CATEGORY","SUBCATEGORY","product_char_name"))
    .withColumn("SALE_PERCENT",col("SALVAL")/col("TOTAL") multiply(100)).withColumn("Versus",lit(item1(3)+" Vs "+item2(3)))
```

With this Code I have generated output. But I want to how to do this for all combination.

Generated Result:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "intersection"? Based on the store ID? And despite being new to Spark, it's encouraged to show your code attempts within the question

Comment: Yes ... its the intersection on stores

Comment: @cricket_007: I have added my code now.